# How do you integrate $x ^ 2 + y ^ 2$ over the area where $x \geq 0, y \geq 0,$ and $3x + 4y <10$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How do you integrate $x ^ 2 + y ^ 2$ over the area where $x \geq 0, y \geq 0,$ and $3x + 4y <10$？

I thought I should use polar coordinates because of the form of the function $x^2+y^2$, but I can't set up the integral properly. How can I calculate this integral?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Your integral can be written in the form of
$$
\int_{a}^b\int_{0}^{d(y)}f(x,y)dxdy
$$

---

You usually don't use polar coordinates when the region of the integral cannot be represented nicely by $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ even though your integrand is a radial function.

When you calculate double integrals on a [normal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Normal_domains_on_R2), you simply use iterated integrals.

[image]

Comment: Yes I understand, but what would the correct integration boundaries look like? something like $$
\int_{0}^{(10-4y)/3}\int_{0}^{(10-3x)/4}f(x,y)dxdy$$? @mrsamy

Comment: @No.iD: You are almost there; but you can't have variables for both integrals. There are two ways to do it; I have shown you one form in the hint. All you need is to figure out the number $b$ and the function $d(y)$.

Comment: Thank you for helping!

Comment: @No.iD: you are welcome.